# Vue - How to use vue-i18n inside a pinia store

Tags: vue.js, pinia, vue-i18n

I am trying to use vue-i18n inside a pinia store's actions block. But I could not get it to work.
Here is my i18n instance:

```js
import en from './en.json'
import ja from './ja.json'

export const createI18nInstance = () => {
    return createI18n({
        legacy: false,
        locale: localStorage.getItem('app-lang') || navigator.language || 'en',
        messages: {
            en,
            'en-US': en,
            ja
        }
    })
}

export const i18n = createI18nInstance()
```

Here is a sample usage. setBanner is a pinia action from another store and takes the translated message as the first argument and passes it tto a bootstrap alert component.

```js
export const useTodos = defineStore("todos", {
    state: () => ({
        todos: [],
    actions: {
        async addTodo(todo) {
            const bannerStore = useBanner()
            try {
                const res = await todoService.addTodo(todo)
                if (res.status === 201) {
                    this.todos.push(todo)
                    bannerStore.setBanner(`${this.$t('successAddSticky')}`, 'success')
                }
            } catch (error) {
                bannerStore.setBanner(`Failed To add todo item ${todo}: ${error}`, 'error')
            }
        },
```

Error:

```
Failed To add todo item [object Object]: TypeError: this.$t is not a function
```

Another attempt that I did:

```js
        async addTodo(todo) {
            const bannerStore = useBanner()
            const { t } = useI18n()
            try {
                const res = await todoService.addTodo(todo)
                if (res.status === 201) {
                    this.todos.push(todo)
                    bannerStore.setBanner(`${t('successAddSticky')}`, 'success')
                }
            } catch (error) {
                bannerStore.setBanner(`Failed To add todo item ${todo}: ${error}`, 'error')
            }
        },Ï
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Must be called at the top of a `setup` function (at vue-i18n.js?v=db96110f:267:17)
```

Comment: What is $t method…? Is it registered as plugin…? Also Is this Nuxt Application ?

Comment: what vuejs version are you using? it's probably got something to do with composition api. have a look at this git issue, https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-composable/issues/14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use i18n global

```js
import { i18n } from "app/i18n"

export const useTodos = defineStore("todos", {
    actions: {
        async addTodo(todo) {
i18n.global.$t("message")
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: It's i18n.global.t, $t is the convention for global "this" properties

Comment: @EstusFlask i asked `kazupon` (author of `vue-i18n`) about this he said that `useI18n` and api are strict it must be used in component setup otherwise it use `i18n.global` i don't remember clearly whether `.t()` or `.$t()` but this is correct